# Flat five chord following a half-dimished chord examples

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions

I have been messing around on the guitar lately and found a short chord progression that goes like this :

Dm7b5 - Bmb5 - Cm

However I would like to know if you could think of pieces that use this sort of sequences and also, what would be the best the best approach to analyse it (from a tonal point of view or not, etc.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis is ii V I in C minor.  The Bmb5, B D F, is G7 with the root missing. Same function, slightly different colour.

Comment: Some people will want to analyse vii as a chord in its own right, with a set of useage rules.  But, without a 7th, it usually pans out as a dominant substitute.  With a 7th, it's typically part of a 'cycle of 5ths' progression, Bm7b5, E7, A7, D7, G7, C.

Comment: I'd analyze that as ii half-diminished 7 - vii° - i of C minor. I call vii° its own chord, but mainly used as a dominant-function chord (so I'm in the "Some people" camp the above comment mentions).

Comment: I think your labelling is a bit mixed up, but we seem to agree, with the 7th it's probably a pre-pre-pre-dominant.    But the chord under discussion is a triad, commonly used adjacent to the tonic chord and acting as its dominant.